# Textbox/Dropdown Combination

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to "combine" the textbox and dropdown box. I can't seem to get them lined up though.

[image]

My code:

```
<input name="" type="text" maxlength="50" style="width: 665px; padding:0px; z-index: 2; position: absolute;" />
<select name="" style="z-index: 1; width: 695px; padding:0px; position:absolute;">
    <option value="Value for Item 1" title="Title for Item 1">Item 1</option>
    <option value="Value for Item 2" title="Title for Item 2">Item 2</option>
    <option value="Value for Item 3" title="Title for Item 3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: BTW: The widget you are attempting to create is called a [combo box](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combo_box).

Comment: The [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w7YdQ/) seems to work fine. `edit`- I mean lined up correctly!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've created a demo for you here: http://jsfiddle.net/aJaa6/

*note that I changed the widths so it would fit in the panel.

CSS:

```
#container
{
    position: relative;
}

#input
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 999;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}

#select
{
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div id="container">
<input id="input" name="" type="" style="width: 100px;">
<br>
<select id="select" name="" style="width: 115px;">
<option value="Value for Item 1" title="Title for Item 1">Item 1</option>
<option value="Value for Item 2" title="Title for Item 2">Item 2</option>
<option value="Value for Item 3" title="Title for Item 3">Item 3</option>
</select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [FlexBox](https://web.archive.org/web/20111017210325/http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox/flexbox-demos/)?  It accomplishes what you want and has a lot of nice customizable features.

Comment: FlexBox (at least in Firefox) is awefully rendered (at least in their sample page that you linked).

Comment: The link is now broken.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to mess around with absolute positions here is a way where if you click on the text box, it displays the drop down. I haven't added in the javascript to hide the dropdown when you click again, but it should be fairly easy to do.

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script>
    function showDrop(){
        $('#select').attr('size',3);
        $("#select").show();
    }
    function populateTextBox(){
            var val = $("#select option:selected").text();
        $("#input").val(val);
    }
   </script>
    </head>
<body>
   <div id="container">
<input id="input" name="" type="" style="width: 100px;" onclick="showDrop();" />
<br>
<select id="select" name="" style="display:none;width: 100px;" onclick="populateTextBox();">
<option value="Value for Item 1" title="Title for Item 1">Item 1</option>
<option value="Value for Item 2" title="Title for Item 2">Item 2</option>
<option value="Value for Item 3" title="Title for Item 3">Item 3</option>
</select>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try this code**

---

```css
#input{ position:absolute; top:2; left:2; z-index:999; padding:0; margin:0; }
#select { position:absolute; top:0; left:0; padding:0; margin:0; }
```

```html
<input id="input" type="text" style="width:100px;">
<select id="selectbox" style="width:123px;">
    <option value="Value for Item 1" title="Title for Item 1">Item </option>
    <option value="Value for Item 2" title="Title for Item 2">Item </option>
    <option value="Value for Item 3" title="Title for Item 3">Item 3</option>
</select>
```